# Using Team Explorer 2010 to connect to TFS 2008 Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

Is this something I shouldn't try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're doing it in our shop, and it's working fine.

http://blogs.msdn.com/teams_wit_tools/archive/2009/10/19/compatibility-matrix-for-2010-beta-2-team-foundation-server-to-team-explorer-2008-and-2005.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Going by this [compatibility matrix](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/teams_wit_tools/2009/10/19/compatibility-matrix-for-2010-beta-2-team-foundation-server-to-team-explorer-2008-and-2005/#_2008_Team_Explorer) you should be fine.

[image]

As an aside connecting from Team Explorer 2008 to TFS 2010 Server is possible with [an update](https://blogs.like10.com/2009/11/20/team-explorer-2008-forward-compatibility-update-for-team-foundation-server-2010/).